# MySQL float rounding

Tags: mysql, database, floating-point, rounding

I have column of type float(12,2) in my table. Why did the number 1399999.05 was rounded to 1399999.00 during the insert operations? As far as I know it rounds numbers if their count of digits more then set in float description. But my number had definitely just two digits.
MySQL version - 5.7

Comment: Given that it's a float, why do you care?

Comment: @Strawberry because there is a big difference between 1399999.05 and 1399999.00 for purposes of my system.

Comment: In which case, you probably shouldn't be using FLOAT!!

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html : "A single-precision floating-point number is accurate to approximately 7 decimal places." You try to enter 9 digits - last 2 digits are truncated by rounding.

Comment: @Akina I have float(12,2) that means 12 digits total with two decimal places. My number has 9 digits total and 2 decimal places. 
There should not be rounding. And you wrote link to MySQL 8 documentation while I have 5.7

Comment: FLOAT cannot store 12 digits - even when you tell it to do this... *you wrote link to MySQL 8 documentation while I have 5.7* No problems, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `DOUBLE` data type here. `FLOAT` only allows about seven significant decimal digits of precision. The numbers represented by the text strings `1399999.05` and `1399999.00` are indistiguishable from each other when converted to [IEEE 32-bit `FLOAT` values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).

MySQL ignores the precision specification for FLOAT, DOUBLE, INT (and TINYINT, SMALLINT, BIGINT) data types. Instead it uses the native data type.   MySQL honors the precision specification for DECIMAL data.

In your case your precision spec is `(12,2)`.

Please consider reading this: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Numbers](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

And, for a hint about what can go wrong when you lose precision you need, [read this](https://thedailywtf.com/articles/classic-wtf-pointless-revenge).

Comment: Re “Counterintuitive, but true”: No, that is not correct. Per IEEE 754, each floating-point datum represents one specific number. It represents that number exactly and does not represent nearby numbers or an interval. In IEEE-754 binary32, 1399999 is representable, and 1399999.05 is not. The model specified in IEEE 754 is that the numbers are exact, and the operations return results that are the real-number arithmetic results rounded to representable values…

Comment: … This model in which numbers are exact but operations approximate real arithmetic is crucial to analyzing and designing floating-point algorithms and to writing proofs about them. The process of converting a decimal numeral, such as one received in text, to binary floating-point is an operation: It produces a result by rounding the real-number result (the exact number represented by the decimal numeral) to a representable number (the exact number represented in the floating-point format). That operation has some rounding error. The result is one number.

Comment: By way of analogy, when we talk about integer arithmetic, we do not say that 3.25 and 3 are the same number because converting either of them from decimal to an integer format yields the same result or because 12/4 and 13/4 both produce 3. 3.25 and 3 are different numbers, and integer arithmetic is simply incapable of representing one of them. They are not “equal to each other” in integer arithmetic. The same is true in floating-point arithmetic. A number that is not representable is not “equal to” a number that is representable.